# Tengo un problema al recibir los datos de una funcion que implementa Fetch en otra

Tags: javascript, fetch

Tengo una funcion search que usa fetch y retorna el json, para no repetir el codigo segun necesite buscar por id o nombre, tengo 2 funciones "searchByName" y "searchById", que arman la url y llaman a search. Luego quisiera retornar estos datos para otras funciones que trabajen los datos. El problema es que me tira undefined (Donde muestro en el comentario). El otro problema es que estoy usando Babel y me tira un error al intentar usar Async/await que creo que solucionaria el problema. Y no he podido resolverlo con promesas dado que aun no las agarro bien jaja espero puedan ayudarme y darme una solucion. Sino no me quedara otra que eliminar search y repetir el fetch dentro de las otras funciones.

```
//Realiza la busqueda
    search(url){
        fetch(url)
        .then( response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response); //Muetra bien el json!!!
            return response;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }   

    //Realiza la busqueda de peliculas por el nombre
    searchByName(name){
        let url = `${this.url}&s=${name}&type=${this.type}`;
        let respuesta = this.search(url);
        console.log(respuesta); // MUESTRA UNDEFINED!!!!!  
        //return this.search(url);      
    }

    //Realiza la busqueda de una unica pelicula mediante un id
    searchById(id){
        let url = `${this.url}&i=${id}`;
        return this.search(url);
    }
```

Comment: Hola, estas cometiendo el mismo error que se comete en el código de una pregunta realizada aquí, quizá te sirva la respuesta que ahí coloque.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/365284/como-recuperar-una-respuesta-obtenida-en-un-callback-as%c3%adncrono/365303#365303

Comment: Gracias, si es lo que sospechaba. Pero al parecer no hay alguna forma de solucionarlo con promesas en la otra funcion.  Solo me quedara resolver el problema que tengo async/await que vi que asi se soluciona facil.